# Xcode 3.2.3 won't symbolicate logs

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode3.2

I'm working with Xcode 3.2.3, which is supposed to symbolicate all crash logs automagically as long as the dSYM archives and the application archive can be found by Spotlight.

I have saved archives of the application and dSYM files for all releases related to these crash logs. Xcode's Organizer shows me memory registers and offsets. It is claiming to symbolicate the logs, but the logs are not getting symbolicated properly.

I have run mdfind in terminal to ensure that Spotlight can find the dSYMs for the applications that are generating crashes, and mdfind is able to find all the dSYM and app files.

How can I get Xcode to symbolicate my logs correctly?

Comment: I've added an iOS tag, though the poster doesn't say whether its's iOS, because I don't think Xcode 3.2.x can symbolicate OS X logs.

Comment: It was in relation to an iOS app I was working on, so that tag is relevant. Also, thank you for cleaning up my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after lunch, I tried symbolicating using XCode 3.1 and it worked.

So here's the scoop - if you have an application that is compiled with XCode 3.2.3 & running on a device with anything earlier than iOS4, the XCode 3.2.3 Organizer will not symbolicate your logs.

You need to install XCode 3.2.1 (or probably 3.2.2) in order to get any symbolication.

And I just found out that XCode 3.2.1 will symbolicate my iOS4 crash logs as well.

Fun times!